# how to check what value is being stored when a selection is done in php

Tags: php, mysql, variables, html-select

I don't think I am passing the 'week_num' numerical value from my drop down to my second page.

```
$wquery="select week_num,week_name from stats_week where season=$this_season order by week_num";
$wresult=mysql_query($wquery);
    print "Select Week:<select name='Week_select'><br>\n";
    while ($wrow=mysql_fetch_array($wresult))
    { 
    print '<option value="'.$wrow['week_num'].'">'.'week '.$wrow['week_num'].'     '.$wrow['week_name'].'</option><br>\n';  
    }
print "</select>";


    print'<button type="submit" >Next</button>';
```

My second page Displays: 
print"
"; week selected = Select team and a drop down box that only includes week 1 teams.

Page 2's beginning code:

```
   $varWeek=#_post['Week_select'];
print "week selected = $varWeek";
 print'<form action="changeplayer_3.php" method="post">';  
  $tquery="select st.team_num,st.name from stats_team st left join stats_results sr on st.team_num=sr.team_num where sr.season=$this_season and sr.week=$varWeek group by st.team_num order by name";
    $tresult=mysql_query($tquery);
    print "Select team:<select name='team_select'><br>\n";
    while ($trow=mysql_fetch_assoc($tresult))
```

Comment: I may be wrong, and haven't researched PHP in a long while, but does that "#_post[]" not need to be "$_POST[]" ? =)

Comment: $varWeek=$_POST['Week_select'];...and the method=post in you first php form ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistake come from this line in your Page 2's beginning code:

```
$varWeek=#_post['Week_select'];
```

It should be

```
$varWeek=$_POST['Week_select'];
```

Comment: WOW! thanks! Now how do I get rid of the 'print"
";' that shows up on page 2 right before the week selected=2?

Comment: found it was a bad form line.